How to use Laplace Transform to convert a function of time domain to a function of frequency domain?
What I was trying to do:
So I was trying to solve for a equation for current( $I(t)$ ) in a buck convertor circuit, and finally after so many mathematical efforts I got the equation, It's just a resistor-inductor circuit connected to PWM(square wave) source, capacitor not included as of now, Anyway after using KVL rule for my specific circuit and solving the first order homogeneous differential equation I ended up with this equation for current,
The equation when PWM square wave is OFF, meaning the inductor is discharging,
\begin{align}
 I(t) &= I_0 \cdot e^{-t/\tau} \qquad \text{$eq.1$} \\\\
\end{align}
And the equation when PWM square wave is ON, meaning the inductor is charging,
\begin{align}
 I(t) &= I_0 \cdot (1 - e^{-t/\tau}) \qquad \text{$eq.2$} \\\\
\end{align}
Where,

$I_0$ = Initial current
$t$ = Time
$\tau$ = Time constant Tau ($L/R$) ,

$L$ = Inductance
$R$ = Resistance



My Question:
Then I realized the above equations are not considering the PWM voltage source the circuit has; I mean there must be a way to get an equation which will consider the fact that the circuit has square wave signal as input voltage source. So I searched a little and found out that, There is a technique which can convert a function from time domain to a function of frequency domain, which is the Laplace Transform.
Tried to get an equation:
So I learned Laplace Transform, But still I am not being able to get that desired equation I want!
Laplace transform of $eq.1$ :
\begin{align}
  \mathscr{L} \{I(t)\} &= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-St} \times I_0 \cdot e^{-Rt/L} \cdot dt \\\\
  &= I_0 \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(-S-R/L)t} \cdot dt \\\\
  &= \frac{I_0}{(-S-R/L)} \cdot \left[ e^{(-S-R/L)t} \right]_{0}^{\infty} \\\\
  &= \frac{I_0}{(-S-R/L)} \cdot  \lim_{A\to \infty} \left[ e^{(-S-R/L)t} \right]_{0}^{A} \\\\
  &= \frac{I_0}{(-S-R/L)} \cdot  \lim_{A\to \infty} \left[e^{(-S-R/L)A}-e^{(-S-R/L)0}\right] \\\\
  \mathscr{L} \{I(t)\} &= \frac{I_0}{ -S - \frac{R}{L} } \qquad , \text{if  $(- S - R/L) < 0$} \\\\
\end{align}
Laplace transform of $eq.2$ :
\begin{align}
  \mathscr{L} \{I(t)\} &= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-St} \times I_0 \cdot (1-e^{-Rt/L}) \cdot dt \\\\
  &= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-St} \times (I_0-I_0e^{-Rt/L}) \cdot dt \\\\
  &= I_0 \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-St} \cdot dt \space - \space I_0 \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-St} e^{-Rt/L} \cdot dt \\\\
  \mathscr{L} \{I(t)\} &= \frac{I_0}{S} \space + \space \frac{I_0}{ S + \frac{R}{L} }  \qquad , \text{if  $S > 0$} \\\\
\end{align}
What now !!! What I should do with these equations? They say $S$ is the frequency but how and what exactly? I am just confused...
What I want:

How to combine $eq.1$ and $eq.2$ to get a single equation?
How to plot the graph considering we have $S$ in our equation?
I just want a single equation to graph it on a XY-plane which considers we have a PWM square wave as an input(source), means ON for half period and OFF for half period.

The graph for my desired equation looks like this(Oscilloscope readings for a RL circuit with PWM wave as source.),

It's not the first time I am asking this question, Through IRC channels and this site I got answers for such an equation which looks like the graph above but I think those are just work arounds, not using Laplace transform to convert a function from time domain to frequency domain.
Work arounds people gave for such a similar equation.
One more similar way, work around.
A kind of similar graph based on the work around not laplace transform.
Final thoughts:
Did I completely misunderstood the Laplace Transform? I know it's heavily used to solve differential equations because it makes them easy to solve. But I believe that's not it, I heard from my teacher Sal that, Using Laplace Transform we can convert a function from time domain to frequency domain. I just wanted that equation for curiosity and I think while building a Buck convertor I spent too much time on learning calculus, differential equations and then the Laplace Transform(Not just that, I had to learn Infinite series also because the concept of Laplace Transform came out from power series.). I am just an engineer who really wants to use math as a tool to build great things.

Here's one powerful application of laplace - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot

For your case I would use Fourier transform. It works better for periodic signals. Note that your integration domain is wrong. Your integrals are from $0$ to $\infty$. But the first equation is from $0$ to $T$, then the second from $T$ to $2T$, first again from $2T$ to $3T$ and so on.

Assuming you turn on the source at time $t=0$, I believe your eq. 2 is correct for $0\le t\le \frac{T}{2}$ where $T$ is the period of the square wave. I don't think your eq. 1 is correct because the initial current at $t=\frac{T}{2}$ is not $I_0$, rather it would be $I_0, \left(1-e^{-\frac{R T}{2 L}}\right)$.

Likewise, the initial current at $t = T$ is not $0$, rather it would be $I_0, \left(1-e^{-\frac{R T}{2 L}}\right), e^{-\frac{R\left(T-\frac{T}{2}\right)}{L}}=I_0, \left(1-e^{-\frac{R T}{2 L}}\right), e^{-\frac{R T}{2 L}}$, so your current waveform is not necessarily periodic, but only approaches periodic as $T$ becomes large enough for the current at $t=\frac{T}{2}$ to approximately reach $I_0$.

@StevenClark So lets say period $T$ is such that current at $t=T/2$ doesn't reach $V/R$, then 1) The waveform will not be periodic? 2) and if so we can't use complex exponential fourier series expansion? 3) and then do I need to use Fourier Transform?

The Fourier series in my answer below is for a function which is periodic for $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Assuming the voltage and current are both zero for $t<0$, the waveform will converge to the periodic function defined in my answer below in the right-half plane as $t\to\infty$. But the Fourier transform of my periodic solution doesn't represent the Fourier transform of the signal assuming the voltage and current are both zero for $t<0$. In this case, I suppose you could derive the Fourier transform piecewise over each half period, but to me the long term behavior of the signal is more informative.

The differential equation for an RL circuit with a voltage input of $V$ is
$$V-R\, i(t)-L\, i'(t)=0\tag{1}$$
with solution
$$i(t)=\frac{V}{R}+a\, e^{-\frac{R t}{L}}\tag{2}$$.
and assuming $i(0)=0$ formula (2) above becomes
$$i(t)=\frac{V}{R}\, \left(1-e^{-\frac{R t}{L}}\right)\tag{3}$$

Assuming $V=0$ in formula (1) above leads to the differential equation
$$-R\, i(t)-L\, i'(t)=0\tag{4}$$
with solution
$$i(t)=b\, e^{-\frac{R t}{L}}\tag{5}$$.
and assuming $i(0)=\frac{V}{R}$ formula (5) above becomes
$$i(t)=\frac{V}{R}\, e^{-\frac{R t}{L}}\tag{6}$$

Formulas (1) to (6) above are consistent with equations (1) and (2) in the question above and with this lesson on RL circuits.

Now assuming a voltage input of
$$v(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & t<0 \\
 V & 0\leq t<\frac{T}{2} \\
 0 & \frac{T}{2}\leq t<T \\
 v(t \bmod T) & T\le t \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{7}$$
the current $i(t)$ in an RL circuit is not necessarily initially periodic, but will eventually become periodic as $t$ increases.

The periodic solution is
$$i(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{V}{R}+a\, e^{-\frac{R t}{L}} & 0\leq t<\frac{T}{2} \\
 b\, e^{-\frac{R \left(t-\frac{T}{2}\right)}{L}} & \frac{T}{2}\leq t<T \\
 i(t \bmod T) & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{8}$$
where
$$a=\frac{V}{R} \left(\frac{1}{e^{\frac{R T}{2 L}}+1}-1\right)\tag{8a}$$
and
$$b=\frac{V}{R}+a\, e^{-\frac{R T}{2 L}}\tag{8b}.$$

The associated Fourier series is
$$i(t)=\lim\limits_{N\to\infty} \sum\limits_{-N}^{N}c_n  e^{\frac{i 2 \pi n x}{T}}\tag{9}$$
where
$$c_n=\frac{1}{T} \int\limits_0^T i(t)\, e^{-\frac{i 2 \pi n t}{T}} \, dt=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{V}{2 R} & n=0 \\
 \frac{\left((-1)^n-1\right) T V}{4 \pi ^2 L n^2-2 i \pi  n R T} & n\neq 0 \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{9a}$$
and note the non-zero frequencies are the odd harmonics of $f=\frac{1}{T}$ (plus the constant offset $c_0$).

Figure (1) below illustrates formula (8) for $i(t)$ above in blue and the related Fourier series defined in formula (9) above in orange where $T=4$, $V=3$, $R=1$, and $L=1$ and formula (9) is evaluated at $N=10$. The dashed-green horizontal grid-line in Figure (1) below is at $\frac{V}{R}$.

Figure (1): Illustration of formula (8) for $i(t)$ (blue) and its related Fourier series (orange)

Figure (2) below illustrates how the current $i(t)$ starting at $t=0$ where $i(0)=0$ in orange gradually converges to the periodic current $i(t)$ defined in formula (8) above in blue where $T=1$, $V=3$, $R=1$, and $L=1$. The dashed-green horizontal grid-line in Figure (2) below is at $\frac{V}{R}$.

Figure (2): Gradual convergence of $i(t)$ starting at $t=0$ where $i(0)=0$ (orange) to the periodic current $i(t)$ (blue)

Hello, I tried so much to understand how 'a' & 'b' are derived but I am still not getting it. Can you please tell me how exactly to find value of $e^k$ at steady state. As of now I tried to get value of that constant K just by step by step changing values, https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a2ode79x4d

And one more question, How you be able to graph the Fourier series for a non-steady, non-periodic equation in Figure(2) which is converging to the blue graph? I mean we can't get Fourier series of a non-periodic function, so we have to imagine a steady state situation.

These are the two equations I have now, $I(t)=V/R - e^ke^-(t/tau)$   &   $I(t)=e^ke^-(t/tau)$

@in.yssh The parameters $a$ and $b$ are derived by solving $i(0)=i(T)$ in formula (8) in my answer above. You know
$$b=\frac{V}{R}+a, e^{-\frac{R T}{L 2}}$$
so you solve
$$i(0)=i(T)\
\frac{V}{R}+a, e^{-\frac{R 0}{L}}=b, e^{-\frac{R \left(T-\frac{T}{2}\right)}{L}}\ \frac{V}{R}+a=\left(\frac{V}{R}+a, e^{-\frac{R T}{L 2}}\right) e^{-\frac{R \left(T-\frac{T}{2}\right)}{L}}$$ for $a$.

@in.yssh The orange curve in Figure (2) is not periodic and therefore not representable by a Fourier series, rather the orange curve in Figure (2) was evaluated iteratively piecewise a half-period at a time starting with the assumption $i(0)=0$ and then using the current at the end of the preceding half-period as the initial current for the subsequent half-period.

Like this or there is a another method? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pizhytlzpf

And is this ok to solve for e^k like this?
\begin{align}
\frac{V}{R}-e^ke^\frac{-0}{\tau} &= e^ke^\frac{-(T-T/2)}{\tau} \\
\frac{V}{R}\frac{1}{e^k}-1 &= e^\frac{-(T-T/2)}{\tau} \\
\frac{V}{R}\frac{1}{e^k} &= e^\frac{-(T-T/2)}{\tau}+1 \\
\frac{1}{e^k} &= \frac{R}{V}(e^\frac{-(T-T/2)}{\tau}+1) \\
e^k &= \frac{V}{R} \times \frac{1}{(e^\frac{-(T-T/2)}{\tau}+1)} \\
\end{align}

Using $T=16 \cdot 10^{-6}$, $R= 96$, $L=0.000990$, and  $V=0.12 \cdot R$ my evaluation seems to match your desmos values for $a_n(x)$ and $b_n(x)$, but your desmos plot doesn't match these values.

The value V/R=0.12 was wrong, R can be 100 ohm, https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tdefhjocdt

@in.yssh My evaluations now seem to match your plot as well as your values for $i\left(n \frac{T}{2}\right)$ in your updated desmos link.

@in.yssh I believe $i(t)$ can be evaluated as
$$i(t)=\left{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{V}{R}+\left(I_0\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2 t}{T}\right\rfloor\right)-\frac{V}{R}\right), e^{-\frac{R}{L} \left(t-\frac{T}{2} \left\lfloor \frac{2 t}{T}\right\rfloor \right)} & \left\lfloor \frac{2 t}{T}\right\rfloor  \bmod 2=0  \
I_0\left(\left\lfloor \frac{2 t}{T}\right\rfloor\right), e^{-\frac{R}{L} \left(t-\frac{T }{2} \left\lfloor \frac{2 t}{T}\right\rfloor \right)} & \text{Otherwise} \
\end{array}\right.\tag{1}$$

where $I_0(n)$ is defined recursively as
$$I_0(n)=\left{\begin{array}{cc}
0 & n=0 \
\frac{V}{R}+\left(I_0(n-1)-\frac{V}{R}\right), e^{-\frac{R}{L} \frac{T}{2}} & n \bmod 2=1 \
I_0(n-1), e^{-\frac{R}{L} \frac{T}{2}} & \text{Otherwise} \
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}$$
but its more efficient to calculate an array of the needed $I_0(n)$ values just once at the beginning of an evaluation and reference the array of $I_0(n)$ values in formula (1) above.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1h4ti11hmb Now I just need solve this equation for different duty cycles of PWM.
